# In IIS 8 my virtual application is resolving to the root rather than itself

Tags: iis, iis-8

In IIS 8 I have a web site set up and a virtual application (not virtual directory), with its own application pool and its own web.config, aspx pages, database, etc.

as an example:

zippy.com  (root application)

zippy.com/app1  (app1 is the virtual application).

When I hit the virtual application from a browser (using zippy.com/app1) it tries to resolve to zippy.com, as if the app1 isn't there at all.  I get a 500 error using a remote browser.

When I use the server's browser so I can see IIS's detailed response I get the following (see image):

[Detailed Error Message from IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTjcL.png)

*Note, I edited the response to obfuscate the real domain and app name, replacing them with zippy.com and a dummy app name.

What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I think I have this issue resolved, but perhaps someone can explain why it was an issue in the first place?  It turns out I had specific Deny rights on the parent site's physical folder for the user used by the virtual app's pool, and the virtual app was looking to the parent's site's web.config (see detailed error message image in original post).  There isn't a web.config file there, but I guess the virtual app needed to look for it, needing rights to do so.  This seems wrong for some reason to me.  There's an inheritance here that I don't understand and would like to disable if I could.